# How to make a circle UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

The following code works on an iPhone but on an iPad the circle is not evenly rounded.

How can I make the view look like a circle on both devices?

```
let width:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.0533      
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
label.layer.cornerRadius = width/2
```

[image]

Comment: I think It seems height is not equal to width..

Comment: One more reason is your button width is a decimal instead of rounded integer. (e.g 33.33 px)

Comment: `label.layer.cornerRadius = min(label.frame.size.width/2, label.frame.size.height/2)`, that makes the round smooth, even if the original frame is not a square.

Answer (score 10):

If you want your UIView to appear as a circle there are couple of ways doing this.

- **Set it's *corner radius* to half of the width/height (most common way)**

If you don't know the height/width of your view in advance. You can simply override `layoutSubviews()` function in it's superview class or `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` function in view controller and set the corner radius directly there.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.width/2
}
```

Don't forget to set the UIView's layer's *masksToBounds* property to true.

- **Set mask layer**

Specify bezier path for the mask layer. Layer's frame must be updated every time the view changes its size.

- **Rounding images**

If you're dealing with images, you can also consider rounding the image itself before displaying it in UIImageView - performance wise it could be a way faster than the previous options.

Answer (score 8):

For making complete circle, you should keep height and width same for your label.
Use this code.

```
let width:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.0533  
label.frame = CGRect(0,0,width,width)    
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
label.layer.cornerRadius = width/2
```

Answer (score 3):

One reason this can happen is if auto layout is changing the size of the label because of a constraint conflict.

Check the debug console to see if thats happening, or just use the "Debug View Hierarchy" to see the actual dimensions of the view.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that to make the uiview circle appart from just .frame.size.height / 2 , width and height of the uiview should be equal.